# Can someone explain the HTML5 aria-* attribute?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

I wanted to know what the `aria-*` attributes are used for. What values can they have, and are they defined values or can I create my own values?

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at the following blogpost ([link](http://blog.gingertech.net/2009/08/21/aria-a-brief-introduction/)) - the poster explains aria and its attributes with a good deal of clarity

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is HTML5 ARIA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474099/what-is-html5-aria)

Answer (score 157):

ARIA stands for [Accessible Rich Internet Applications](http://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/aria/) and is designed to improve the accessibility of Rich Internet Applications, i.e. to make them more usable for people with disabilities.

Help on the various attributes is available [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.2/#global_states).

I don't think you can create your own ARIA attributes.

Comment: the 'various attributes' link is no good right at the moment.

Comment: Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA for an overview.

Comment: @gkrogers is right. You can't create your own aria attributes. The `data-` attribute prefix should be used for that (and there's some javaScript sugar for accessing them).