# What is the definition of the HTML5 aria-* attribute in laymans terms?

Tags: html

What is the definition of the HTML5 aria-* attribute in laymans terms?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can someone explain the HTML5 aria-* attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176844/can-someone-explain-the-html5-aria-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

Accessibility of web content requires semantic information about widgets, structures, and behaviors, in order to allow assistive technologies to convey appropriate information to persons with disabilities. This specification provides an ontology of roles, states, and properties that define accessible user interface elements and can be used to improve the accessibility and interoperability of web content and applications. These semantics are designed to allow an author to properly convey user interface behaviors and structural information to assistive technologies in document-level markup.