# How to change max value of Bootstrap progressbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Basically I got 7 "steps" of my progressbar - the default max value is 100 so 100/7 doesn't divide into whole numbers.

Therefore I'd like to change the max value of the progressbar to, for instance, 7.

```
   <div id="wizard-progressbar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
      <span class="sr-only">0% Complete</span>
   </div>
```

I've tried changing the **aria-valuemax** and tried setting **data-max** but none of them changes anything. How can I change the max value of my Bootstrap progressbar?

Comment: @DanKanze A thousand pardons but I don't quite follow you?

Comment: If your form has 7 steps, set your max to 7. Then set your value to the current step. So 1/7 is page 1 or whatever.

Comment: @DanKanze When you say "set your max to 7" are you referring to the progress bar max value? I mean how to set that max value is my exact question...

Comment: The aria values are very similar to "alt" tags in a way that it helps with accessibility (read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176844/can-someone-explain-the-html5-aria-attribute).

In your case, changing values does not make visual changes. You still have to rely on that percentage width. While its true that dividing 100 by 7 does not give you whole numbers, and since it looks like you are hard coding the values in, you might as well go with the closest rounded value like add 14.28 or 14.3 to every each 7 steps and make the last one 100%.

Answer (score 10):

`aria-valuenow`, `aria-valuemin` and `aria-valuemax` are meta-datas. The progress bar style is not dependent on their value.

Then you should use :

- `aria-valuemin="0"`
- `aria-valuemax="7"`

The active value is this one : `style="width: 0%;"`. You'll need to set it manually to :

- 0%
- 14.3%
- 28.6%
- 42.9%
- 57.2%
- 71.5%
- 85.8%
- 100%

[**Bootply**](http://bootply.com/112942)

If you want to set this width automatically, you can do it using JS :

```
$('.progress-bar').each(function() {
  var min = $(this).attr('aria-valuemin');
  var max = $(this).attr('aria-valuemax');
  var now = $(this).attr('aria-valuenow');
  var siz = (now-min)*100/(max-min);
  $(this).css('width', siz+'%');
});
```

[**Bootply**](http://bootply.com/112944)

Comment: Seemingly this is the solution, but didn't work for me.

Comment: Seems to be the only source all over the Internet where "area-valuemin" is well explained and the css:width is calculated correctly.