# HTML5 Syntax Validation

Tags: html, w3c-validation

I was validating some HTML and I noticed some new errors that I am unfamiliar with. These list items get populated with JavaScript based on user input.

> Element `li` is missing one or more of the following attributes: `aria-checked`, `aria-expanded`, `aria-valuemax`, `aria-valuemin`, `aria-valuenow`, `aria-valuetext`, `role`

```
<ul id="outTag">
    <li id="item1"></li>
    <li id="item2"></li>
    <li id="item3"></li>
    <li id="item4"></li>
</ul>
```

If someone could please shed some light on this, that would be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is HTML5 ARIA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474099/what-is-html5-aria)

Comment: @MattBall: This is not a duplicate, as this question is about why missing ARIA attributes are reported as error, and not what ARIA is.

Comment: Same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16123276/1591669

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, it's a validator issue as described [here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator-cvs/2013Apr/0038.html). It should be fixed soon.