# HTML5 validator Errors:Element li is missing one or more of the following attributes: aria-checked, aria-expanded, aria-valuemax, aria-valuem

Tags: html, validation, w3c

HTML 5 code that used pass without errors few days ago are now showing errors when I run it through W3C validator. Errors look something like this:

**Element li is missing one or more of the following attributes: aria-checked, aria-expanded, aria-valuemax, aria-valuemin, aria-valuenow, aria-valuetext, role.**

Any idea what's going on and how do I get rid of these errors?

Comment: Refer this to understand what ARIA means : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474099/what-is-html5-aria

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Syntax Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122893/html5-syntax-validation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an error of the W3C validator. It will be fixed.

From http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-validator-cvs/2013Apr/0038.html:

> It's a validator issue. I made some updates today today to the ARIA support and
>   it seems I likely introduced some unintended change. Thanks for the heads up. I
>   will look into it and fix it as soon as possible and then respond here again.

Comment: Thanks. Hope they fix it soon!!